# Is there any port that can be used to broadcast to every process?

Tags: c++, linux, networking, udp

I want to broadcast a UDP message to all process. Like 255.255.255.255 is used to broadcast to all ips, is there any port to broadcast to every proceses?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Won't most of those processes not understand what you're sending them?

Comment: Actually I'm forking some process and then I want to send them same message through UDP (it's requirement of the assignment), I thought broadcast would be an easy solution.

Comment: Do you mean: "broadcast to every port"? Not sure how the concept of processes has anything to do with UDP

Comment: Yes, broadcast to every port. It's my assignment, the assignment requires to spawn multiple processes through fork() and then send them a message through UDP.

Comment: [Does this help?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9310749/220636)

Comment: noop...that's about broadcast to ips. I think blueshift is right, there's no way to do that

Comment: If they are your own processes why exactly do you need to flood every port in the LAN?

Comment: I don't know why this is getting downvoted. It's a legitimate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

That's the short answer. The rest of this answer is just to get over the length limit.

Comment: @MartinJames What makes you think I don't understand the question?

Comment: @MartinJames And how do you know he didn't understand the question?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to broadcast to every process on a local system, like we send out UDP broadcasts on a network?

For Windows, you can see this. This is no about processes, but about services.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685149(v=vs.85).aspx

It might be theoretically possible to get a list of services, and call their Service Control Handlers. I am not sure if it can be implemented at all, and my best guess is it cannot.

I understand that you are going to throw the same "the assignment requires it" answer, but I am very interested to know what you are trying to achieve, by broadcasting to all processes.