# Boost.Asio - How to send a message to multiple clients

Tags: c++, boost-asio, tcpserver

I have been looking at a lot of Boost.Asio tutorials, especially this one:
[TCP daytime server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html)

After a server creates a tcp_connection with a client, it seems like the communication is only one-way between the server and that specific client. How can I make it so a server has the ability to relay client messages to all of the clients connected? Or even choose which clients to send messages to.

Answer (score 0):

TCP create only connexion between the server and a specific client. You can use UDP connexion to broadcast message to several clients.

Like JTejedor says in comments, you can also create a TCP socket for each client.

Comment: You can use UDP broadcast. Here is a question related to how create UDP broadcast using Boost [UDP broadcasting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310231/boostasio-udp-broadcasting). But if you prefer use TCP, you need to create a connection with each client and send any message to each client explicity.