# Simple udp broadcast server using boost::asio

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio, broadcast

I tried to build simplest udp broadcast server using `boost::asio`
Here is my code inspired by answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310231/boostasio-udp-broadcasting):

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

const int port = 1356;

int main() {
    boost::system::error_code error;
    using boost::asio::ip::udp;

    udp::endpoint endpoint(
        boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"),
        port);
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    udp::socket sock(ios);
    sock.open(udp::v4(), error);
    if (error) {
        std::cerr << "Error while opening socket\n";
        return -1;
    }
    sock.set_option(udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
    sock.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::broadcast(true));

    std::string data = "Hello world!";
    while(true) {
        sock.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(data), endpoint);
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It is not working as I expected. I got `send: Connection refused`. I expect that server sending data with no error and then clients will connect.
Something wrong with my expectations or with the code?

Comment: UDP is not a connected protocol, and if the other end is not actively listening on connections it will not work to connect to it. And if you want to *broadcast*, what should you really *connect* to? Please take some time to study more about UDP sockets and broadcasting using them.

Comment: By the way, you actually try to connect to *yourself* using the only partially initialized `endpoint`. I say it's partially initialized because it's missing an address. Perhaps you meant to *bind* the socket instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I really have not enough knowledge in broadcasting. If you know good article - please share.
In this code I tried to make server that broadcast data at `127.0.0.1:1356`. I planned to write client code that conenct to  `127.0.0.1:1356` and read data. Success for me if I launch several clients and all of them receive same data.   
I edited code in answer. Now I don't have this crash. Thank you. (But I still not sure that I thinking in right direction)

Comment: Broadcast means you send/receive your datagrams to a special broadcast IP address (127.0.0.1 is not a broadcast address, it is a unicast address).

Comment: Seems to me there is no active connection listeners at 1356 port. Try first to connect to port using `nc -u localhost 1356`

Comment: @DmytroDadyka I don't have `nc` on this machine. But thanks for the tip