# UDP directed broadcast (WinSock2) failure

Tags: udp, broadcast, winsock2

Let me start by saying this is my first foray into the world of C after 20+ years of assembly programming for PLCs and MicroControllers.

I'm trying to send a UDP datagram to the network broadcast address, in this particular case, 192.168.1.255.

The error I'm getting is a bind failure with error code 10049 (from WSAGetLastError()). As you can see from the attached code, I've created the socket, populated sockaddr_in, and setsockopt() to SO_BROADCAST.

For the life of me I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and any pointers would be gratefully received.

```
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaTxData);
if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
{
    WSAErrorString("WSAStartup for TX failed");
    return(-1);
}
XPLMDebugString("UDP Server: WSAStartup TX complete.\n");

if ((BeaconSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    WSAErrorString("UDP Server: Could not create BECN socket");
    return(-1);
}

// setup the sockaddr_in structure
//
si_beacon.sin_family = AF_INET;
si_beacon.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.255");
si_beacon.sin_port = htons(_UDP_TX_PORT);

// setup to broadcast
//
char so_broadcast_enabled = '1';
if (setsockopt(BeaconSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &so_broadcast_enabled, sizeof(so_broadcast_enabled)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    WSAErrorString("Error in setting Broadcast option");
    closesocket(BeaconSocket);
    return(-1);
}

// bind our socket
//
if (bind(BeaconSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&si_beacon, sizeof(si_beacon)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    char buf[256];
    WSAErrorString("Bind to socket for UDP beacon failed");
    sprintf(buf, "Port %u, address %s\n", ntohs(si_beacon.sin_port), inet_ntoa(si_beacon.sin_addr));
    XPLMDebugString(buf);
    return(-1);
}

// start the UDP beacon
//
udp_becn_thread_id = CreateThread(NULL, 0, BeaconThread, NULL, 0, NULL);
if (!udp_becn_thread_id) {
    WSAErrorString("UDP Server: Error starting UDP Beacon");
    return (-1);
}

XPLMDebugString("UDP Server: bind complete. beacon ACTIVE.\n");


return(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the IP address itself.

I copied the code to my computer (changed it a bit to get it to compile) and I got the error:

```
UDP Server: WSAStartup TX complete.
Bind to socket for UDP beacon failed
Port 47977, address 192.168.1.255
```

I then changed the line:

```
si_beacon.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.255");
```

To

```
si_beacon.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.127");
```

And when I ran it again, everything worked:

```
UDP Server: WSAStartup TX complete.
Done successfully
```

The issue is that the "bind" address needs to be **your** computers address on the local network. **Not** the remote client.

Another alternative is to use the address:

```
si_beacon.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0");
```

which binds to all network interfaces on the computer at once.

For reference, here's the version of the code that I used:

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h> // For inet_pton

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    {
        WSADATA wsaTxData;
        memset(&wsaTxData, 0, sizeof(WSADATA));
        const int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaTxData);
        if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
        {
            printf("%s", "WSAStartup for TX failed.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        printf("%s", "UDP Server: WSAStartup TX complete.\n");
    }

    SOCKET BeaconSocket;
    memset(&BeaconSocket, 0, sizeof(SOCKET));

    if ((BeaconSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("%s", "UDP Server: Could not create BECN socket\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // setup the sockaddr_in structure
    //
    sockaddr_in si_beacon;
    memset(&si_beacon, 0, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
    si_beacon.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_beacon.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0");
    const unsigned short port_num = 0xbb69;
    si_beacon.sin_port = htons(port_num);

    // setup to broadcast
    //
    char so_broadcast_enabled = '1';
    if (setsockopt(BeaconSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &so_broadcast_enabled, sizeof(so_broadcast_enabled)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("%s", "Error in setting Broadcast option\n");
        closesocket(BeaconSocket);
        return(-1);
    }

    // bind our socket
    //
    if (bind(BeaconSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&si_beacon, sizeof(si_beacon)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        char buf[256];
        printf("%s", "Bind to socket for UDP beacon failed\n");
        sprintf_s(buf, "Port %u, address %s\n", ntohs(si_beacon.sin_port), inet_ntoa(si_beacon.sin_addr));
        printf("%s", buf);
        return(-1);
    }

    printf("%s", "Done successfully");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think I've got that. So when I come to transmit the beacon using sendto(), I guess I'll need a second sockaddr_in structure populated for the target address of 192.168.1.255. Would that be correct? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I know very little about the Win32API, but it's terrible. If I were you I would be using C++ with boost::asio. Here is how to broadcast UDP with boost::asio https://stackoverflow.com/a/9310749/7753444 The API that winsock2 uses is the pinnacle of C being "efficiently dangerous". In any case I'm sure there are libraries in C for UDP broadcasting. You don't need to use the Win32API. There are too many places to go wrong.